# Symfony2 deployment to ubunt server

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, routes

I am new to server deployment and I have recently deployed my symfony website to a ubuntu based server. In order to run my website without specification of `app.php` I added `DirectoryIndex app.php` in my apache conf so my website is visible on www.abc.com however any other link is not working;

for example the link below does not work

```
www.abc.com/route
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on ubuntu and have root access, try adding this virtualhost into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName abc.com
     ServerAlias abc.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/abc.com.log
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc.com/web/

<Directory /var/www/html/abc.com/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thnx. but if in a particular URL app.php is not added how can it be done automatically like abc.com/route should redirect to abc.com/app.php/route

Comment: If you have a route named /route in your route configuration, abc.com/app.php/route will be abc.com/route

Comment: I have implemented your changes but abc.com does not redirect to abc.com/app.php

Comment: Instead it shoes directory list

Comment: But I think it has more to do with symfony rather than the server, I will delete the question from here

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: Yes I have restarted it